# How to use Java BufferedImage and Robot in the ideal way for memory management?

Tags: java, memory-management, bufferedimage, awtrobot

I'm new to object oriented programming. I have made a class with a static method that captures various different sized rectangles of my screen at various intervals. The captures are stored in a static BufferedImage using a static Robot instance:

```
myStaticBufferedImage = myStaticRobot.createScreenCapture(arbitrarySizeRectangle);
```

Some operations are performed on the data (including occasionally writing the image to a bmp file). Upon the next capture, none of the image data from the previous capture is needed.

Since the bufferedImage will contain variable size data up to the full size of my screen resolution, should I declare it as so before my Application starts using it?

```
private static BufferedImage myStaticBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(RESOLUTION_X, RESOLUTION_Y, APPROPRIATE_IMAGE_TYPE);
```

Does this allocate a reusable chunk in memory without any leaks or inefficiencies as I repeatedly capture images? Or is the createScreenCapture method filling more and more memory each time I use it and simply assigning a new pointer to myStaticBufferedImage?

I'm running this app on OSX Lion alongside some CPU-intensive software. What is the best practice for memory management? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not initialize `myStaticBufferedImage` to the largest resolution. `createScreenCapture()` will create its own `BufferedImage` in memory, and then `myStaticBufferedImage` will be referred to that. In no case will `createScreenCapture()` use the buffer from `myStaticBufferedImage`.

That said, if you'll only be creating a few `BufferedImage`s, it probably won't make a difference next to the very CPU-intensive (memory-intensive?) software.

Comment: I just found the source code for createScreenCapture and came to the same realization. I will be capturing more than a few - more like a few every minute over the course of a few hours before the application is terminated. I'm worried about memory, but maybe the Java 6 garbage collector will take care of everything for me.

Comment: Ah, I see. However, as I understand it, you only have one `BufferedImage` at a time, so you should not be able to run out of memory. You can fine tune the gc by using the JVM parameter `-XX:NewRatio=10` - a larger number essentially invokes the gc more quickly on transient objects. You could also invoke it directly: `Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime(); r.gc();`